# CSS Selecting First Child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Im still trying to figure out how to properly use my `nth`, `first`, and `last` child selectors. Thanks for your patience.

If my markup is like this:

```
<div class="the-wrapper">
    <table class="the-table">
       <!-- the table -->
    </table>

    <table class="the-table">
       <!-- the table -->
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I select the last `<table class="the-table">` to apply a margin?

I thought I could select it like this: `.the-wrapper .the-table:last-child { /* css */ }` but this does not work. What am I missing? Thank you!

EDIT

---

Sorry everyone I printed my markup incorrectly... The correct markup is above

Comment: You need to use the plus sign for this as `.the-wrapper + .the-table:last-child { /* propertiest */`. THe plus makes sure the CSS is being applied where both these classes are available.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but that has not worked for me

Comment: Before attempting any of the posted solutions, first check to make sure the browsers you're targeting [actually support these pseudo-classes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: Im using Firefox 22 and have been able to select `nth` and child elements on other pages, but I'm not sure what the problem is here. I'm starting to think maybe there is a problem in the markup (which I did not create). Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r95gz/1/). If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate it! This has been killing me (haha)!

Comment: In case why not simply use `.the-table:last-child {}`? Does this help?

Comment: Thanks but I need to be more specific with my selector to avoid selecting similar elements on other pages. Thank you though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` is used to select "siblings" elements. (siblings in the sense of being childs of the same parent) http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmjq/

You can't use `nth-child` or `last-child` for this; as the name say, is for `childs`, and unless you put a parent, you can't do it.

Here is an example *with* a parent: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmjq/2/ In this case, is done with `last-child`

---

(**updated to your new code**)
Here is a tiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmjq/4/

```
.the-wrapper .the-table:last-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

---

Updated with your new code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmjq/4/

Comment: Ok thanks yeh I understand that. However, I put `.the-wrapper:last-child .the-table { color: red; }` and it turned both instances of `.the-table` to red.. Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh sorry I actually printed my markup wrong! Sorry for the confusion! Edited above: (the wrapper holds both of the child elements)

Comment: @Dude, ok, I updated the fiddle with your new code. **edit**: did a mistake, update it again: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmjq/4/

Comment: Thanks @chris-I. This is what I thought initially. Trying `.the-wrapper .table-wrapper:last-child` does not target anything though, for some reason. Im so confused why this doesnt work, but it works in the jsfiddle as you have shown. My markup has a few additional elements, but the structure is the same as above: there are multiple instances of `the-table` inside `the-wrapper`. Have you ever encountered anything like this?

Comment: @Dude, I can take a look to your code if you put it on a fiddle.

Comment: @Dude, No, I haven't had problems like that. Check this fiddle, it has two `the-wrapper` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmjq/5/

Comment: FYI, the `+` combinator is used to select [adjacent siblings](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent). For [general siblings](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general) use the `~` combinator.

Comment: @AndréDion Oh interesting, I didn't knew that one. thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot @chris-I. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r95gz/1/). If you have a second to check it out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: For reason, I can't do it with `last-child`, but using nth-child it works: http://jsfiddle.net/r95gz/3/ Why `nth-child(4)`? why 4? Something is weird, I'll check some more.

Comment: Ok, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/r95gz/8/ I removed the last `<br>` and closed the `<div>`. I guess that unclosed div somehow activated a quirks mode or something, but anyway, it works now.

Comment: Yeh that is really strange, but thank you so much for the help! Would have taken me a lot longer to figure out on my own!

Answer (score 1):

```
.the-wrapper .the-table:last-child { /* css */ }
```

The previous code should select the last table in the wrapper. The targeting for structural pseudo classes can be confusing. The pseudo classes are defined in regards to it's direct parent. For instance, say you have a list of elements:

```
<ul class="target-me">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

and you want to target the last `li` in the list. Your CSS would be:

```
.target-me > li:last-child { color: red; }
```

You can also use the pseudo selectors to target numbered items from the position in the DOM, say I want to target the second element:

```
.target-me > li:nth-child(2) { color: red; }
```

You can also use these pseudo selectors in a selector hierarchy.

```
.target-me > li:first-child span { ... }
```

You can also chain pseudo selectors:

```
.target-me > li:first-child:hover { ... }
```

In conjunction with a polyfill like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) you can use these selectors on all browsers. I hope this helps!

Comment: I believe the OP wants to select the table and this would select the div parent. You may want `.the-wrapper:last-child .the-table{`.

Comment: Ok maybe I didn't explain it correctly. I want to select the last instance of `the-table` and apply a margin to it. I tried `.the-wrapper:last-child .the-table { color: red; }` and it selected both instances of `the-table` rather than just the last one. Any ideas why this may happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your code "`.the-wrapper .the-table:last-child` " will return the last-child elements of ALL your "`.the-wrapper`" classes.  What you want to do is select the last "`.the-wrapper`" element.  The code below will select the last-child table of the last "`.the-wrapper`" element, which is what you are looking for...

```
$('.the-wrapper .the-table:last-child').last().css("border","1px solid #b5b5b5")
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a pure css solution.